# propane Fireplace insert not working properly after I ran out of gas

Tags: propane

Gas man filled my empty 100 gallon tank.  Claimed there was a small leak.  I told him that I did not turn anything off inside the fireplace when I ran out of gas.  He red tagged the tank and fireplace.  Then,a technician from the gas company came out.  Decided I did not have a leak, after he turned off the inside lever to pilot light.   Took logs apart, sprayed liquid all over joints, valves, and pilot.  Got the fireplace to light but then had blue flames flying way above the logs, looked like the "northern lights" in my fire place.  The front flames on left side started to go out and then the entire front bar and partial back bar went out leaving only a huge orange flame on the  right side of the back row nearest the pilot.   I told the tech, Everything worked fine before I ran out of gas....
Now the technician is sending out a expert Technician in two weeks to trouble shoot some more.    Any suggestions on what I may try in the mean time?  What may be going on?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If the answer is good, please check the checkmark next to it to mark it as "accepted." And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the pressure has increased. Perhaps a valve needs to be replaced.

For your safety, I’d turn it off and keep it off until the technician arrives in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

“Flames way above the logs” sounds like the pressure is too high, which sounds like the regulator needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

If it was my system I would purge the lines, the color difference and possible high flow could be sign of something got stuck in the regulator and a short high flow of the gas line may clear it.